# Updating format in multiple sheets

Tags: excel, vba, loops, formatting

i am not sure if i am written the right code .
 I have 20 sheets in a workbook and i would like to format column B:B where sheet name like "data*". I have written the below code which doesn't seem to do anything and when i try to test this code it doesnt stop.The loop doesnt stop.

Could someone please advice what am i doing wrong or correct my code please.

```
Sub dtupdate()

    For Each sheet In Application.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        If sheet.Name Like "*Data*" Then
            Range("B:B").Select
            'Columns("B:B").Select
            'st.Ranges("B2", ActiveSheet.Ranges("B2").End(xlDown)).Select
            Selection.NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"  
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: no caps needed in the title...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
Sub dtupdate()
    Dim sh As Worksheet

    For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If sh.Name Like "*Data*" Then _
            sh.Range("B:B").NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
    Next
End Sub
```